# CKEditor protect content (widgets?)

Tags: javascript, php, ckeditor

So, I have articles in a database, and I want to see if I can make use of CKEditor to edit them.

Some of them have "keyword" that in turn is expanded by PHP to something else. For instance, if I write "[FAQLIST:12,34,56]" it will show a UL of all the FAQ's with ID 12, 34 and 56. But I obviously don't want CKEditor to edit this resulting code. So I've read about widgets and wonder whether this is something I can use that for. Or is there some code I can wrap my HTML in to make CKEditor treat it is non-editable content within a contenteditable area?

Comment: So PHP will parse this tags to UL and echo to html? How about just submit to CKEditor unparsed article ?

Answer (score 0):

I read another your question, you want to use it with inline ckeditor.

As option you can specify `contenteditable="false"` attribute on `ul` tag (or which tag surrounds [FAQLIST:12,34,56])